# What Elasticsearch analyzer should I use to search hybrid english words, product information?

Tags: elasticsearch, nest

My team is attempting to index our item information and need a sanity check on what I have created so far. Here is an example of some of the text we need to search on:

AA4VG90EP4DM1/32R-NSF52F001DX-S WITH DAMAN MANIFOLD 0281CS0011 SIEMENS SPEC 74/07104909/10 REV L  WOMACK SYSTEMS

As you can see there is a mix of english words and random numbers and letters. After doing some research online I decided to go with a word delimiter and whitespace tokenizer. Here is the analyzer I am currently using:

```
 {
   {
   "itemindex": {
      "settings": {
         "index": {
            "uuid": "1HxasKSCSW2iRHf6pYfkWw",
            "analysis": {
               "analyzer": {
                  "my_analyzer": {
                     "type": "custom",
                     "filter": [
                        "lowercase",
                        "my_word_delimiter"
                     ],
                     "tokenizer": "whitespace"
                  }
               },
               "filter": {
                  "my_word_delimiter": {
                     "type_table": "/ => ALPHANUM",
                     "preserve_original": "true",
                     "catenate_words": "true",
                     "type": "word_delimiter"
                  }
               }
            },
            "number_of_replicas": "1",
            "number_of_shards": "5",
            "version": {
               "created": "1000099"
            }
         }
      }
   }
}
```

Here is the output from the analyze api for the above description:

```
    {
   "tokens": [
      {
         "token": "aa4vg90ep4dm1/32r-nsf52f001dx-s",
         "start_offset": 0,
         "end_offset": 31,
         "type": "word",
         "position": 1
      },
      {
         "token": "aa",
         "start_offset": 0,
         "end_offset": 2,
         "type": "word",
         "position": 1
      },
      {
         "token": "4",
         "start_offset": 2,
         "end_offset": 3,
         "type": "word",
         "position": 2
      },
      {
         "token": "vg",
         "start_offset": 3,
         "end_offset": 5,
         "type": "word",
         "position": 3
      },
      {
         "token": "90",
         "start_offset": 5,
         "end_offset": 7,
         "type": "word",
         "position": 4
      },
      {
         "token": "ep",
         "start_offset": 7,
         "end_offset": 9,
         "type": "word",
         "position": 5
      },
      {
         "token": "4",
         "start_offset": 9,
         "end_offset": 10,
         "type": "word",
         "position": 6
      },
      {
         "token": "dm",
         "start_offset": 10,
         "end_offset": 12,
         "type": "word",
         "position": 7
      },
      {
         "token": "1/32",
         "start_offset": 12,
         "end_offset": 16,
         "type": "word",
         "position": 8
      },
      {
         "token": "r",
         "start_offset": 16,
         "end_offset": 17,
         "type": "word",
         "position": 9
      },
      {
         "token": "nsf",
         "start_offset": 18,
         "end_offset": 21,
         "type": "word",
         "position": 10
      },
      {
         "token": "rnsf",
         "start_offset": 16,
         "end_offset": 21,
         "type": "word",
         "position": 10
      },
      {
         "token": "52",
         "start_offset": 21,
         "end_offset": 23,
         "type": "word",
         "position": 11
      },
      {
         "token": "f",
         "start_offset": 23,
         "end_offset": 24,
         "type": "word",
         "position": 12
      },
      {
         "token": "001",
         "start_offset": 24,
         "end_offset": 27,
         "type": "word",
         "position": 13
      },
      {
         "token": "dx",
         "start_offset": 27,
         "end_offset": 29,
         "type": "word",
         "position": 14
      },
      {
         "token": "s",
         "start_offset": 30,
         "end_offset": 31,
         "type": "word",
         "position": 15
      },
      {
         "token": "dxs",
         "start_offset": 27,
         "end_offset": 31,
         "type": "word",
         "position": 15
      },
      {
         "token": "with",
         "start_offset": 32,
         "end_offset": 36,
         "type": "word",
         "position": 16
      },
      {
         "token": "daman",
         "start_offset": 37,
         "end_offset": 42,
         "type": "word",
         "position": 17
      },
      {
         "token": "manifold",
         "start_offset": 43,
         "end_offset": 51,
         "type": "word",
         "position": 18
      },
      {
         "token": "0281cs0011",
         "start_offset": 52,
         "end_offset": 62,
         "type": "word",
         "position": 19
      },
      {
         "token": "0281",
         "start_offset": 52,
         "end_offset": 56,
         "type": "word",
         "position": 19
      },
      {
         "token": "cs",
         "start_offset": 56,
         "end_offset": 58,
         "type": "word",
         "position": 20
      },
      {
         "token": "0011",
         "start_offset": 58,
         "end_offset": 62,
         "type": "word",
         "position": 21
      },
      {
         "token": "siemens",
         "start_offset": 63,
         "end_offset": 70,
         "type": "word",
         "position": 22
      },
      {
         "token": "spec",
         "start_offset": 71,
         "end_offset": 75,
         "type": "word",
         "position": 23
      },
      {
         "token": "74/07104909/10",
         "start_offset": 76,
         "end_offset": 90,
         "type": "word",
         "position": 24
      },
      {
         "token": "rev",
         "start_offset": 91,
         "end_offset": 94,
         "type": "word",
         "position": 25
      },
      {
         "token": "l",
         "start_offset": 95,
         "end_offset": 96,
         "type": "word",
         "position": 26
      },
      {
         "token": "womack",
         "start_offset": 98,
         "end_offset": 104,
         "type": "word",
         "position": 27
      },
      {
         "token": "systems",
         "start_offset": 105,
         "end_offset": 112,
         "type": "word",
         "position": 28
      }
   ]
}
```

Finally, here is the NEST query I am using:

```
var results = client.Search<SearchResult>(s => s.Index("itemindex")
            .Query(q => q
                .QueryString(qs=> qs
                    .OnFields(f=> f.Description, f=> f.VendorPartNumber, f=> f.ItemNumber)
                    .Operator(Operator.or)
                    .Query(query + "*")))
                    .SortDescending("_score")
                .Highlight(h => h
                    .OnFields(f => f
                    .OnField(e => e.Description)
                    .BoundaryCharacters(" ,")
                    .PreTags("<b>")
                    .PostTags("</b>")))
               .From(start)
               .Size(size));
```

Comment: I'm unclear what your desired use case is. How would you expect a user to search against this field?

Comment: It would be a free form search box, where they could search on the description, item number or vendor part number. This is being used to power autocompletion.